# Brave Browser - disable import bookmarks

Tags: brave

I have recently installed brave and it is currently prompting me to import bookmarks and is annoying - any suggestion on how to disable it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to settings and search for "Always show bookmarks on New tab page" then toggle it off, the import bookmarks prompt will not be shown anymore[image].

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings > Toggle show bookmarks

OR

Add bookmarks if you want. If you add any bookmark, it will go away. If you don't want any bookmarks but want to keep that panel you can add a dummy bookmark that will open a new tab. To do that add bookmark with URL as `chrome://newtab` you can also make it so that the bookmarks appear on new tabs only and not on open webpages.

Comment: This sounds like removing a splinter by amputating the limb.

Comment: @Scott Ya, but doesn't seem like he wants bookmarks, if he adds any bookmarks, it will go away automatically. He can add a dummy bookmark of `New Tab` if he wants.

Comment: Now ***that*** sounds like an answer.

Comment: @Scott I have updated  the answer